# Getting exception object address from catch (...) c++

Tags: c++, try-catch

I have a sample try/catch block.

```
try
{
...
}
catch (...)
{
...
}
```

Is there any way to get exception object address or something from inside of catch(...) block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *kind of* do this in C++11 by using [`std::current_exception()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/current_exception/) which returns "an `exception_ptr` object that points to the currently handled exception, or to a copy of it." However, as covered in other answers, since you have no idea what the type actually is, this is hardly useful. Note that very few operations are defined for [`std::exception_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/exception_ptr/), and in fact dereferencing it "causes undefined behavior."

About the only interesting thing you can do with it is save the pointer so that you can later rethrow it in another context using [`std::rethrow_exception`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/rethrow_exception/). This is covered in some detail on the [MSDN article "Transporting Exceptions Between Threads."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293602.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If you know at least something about the type, then yes.

The `catch(...)` syntax does not give a name to the exception object, but it is possible to rethrow the object and use a more specific `catch` clause:

```
try {
    throw 0;
}
catch(...)
{
    try {
        throw;
    }
    catch(int &i)
    {
        std::cout << &i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see no difference between your suggestion and try(){}catch(SpecificExceptionType1 e2){}(SpecificExceptionType2 e2){}(int& i){}

Comment: It is also acceptable to move the entire contents of the outer `catch` clause to a separate function, so if you have several places that call some external code that might throw anything, there is no need to repeat the exception handler at all call sites; rather, you place a catch-all around each call, and handle the exceptions in a common handler function.

Comment: Hello, I think this is a great answer. I have been looking for some time to find evidence in the standards documents that this is standard behavior, but have been unable to find any. Do you know for certain that this is standard behavior? (That is, entering a new `try`-block inside a `catch(...){}` and rethrowing an exception in order to determine its type.)

Answer (score 1):

How would you use the address?

You can catch most exceptions by

```
try {
    // something
}
catch (const std::exception& e)
{
    // e will be anything derived from std::exception
}
catch(...)
{
    // any other error, that you know nothing about
    // possibly log it as a problem, and
    throw;    // pass it on to someone else that might know how to handle it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do just that because the thrown object can be of any possible type, including the plain old data, such as int or double. There is no way to deduce the actual type of it.

Even if the language gave you a pointer to the object, you wouldn't be able to do anything useful with it anyways, at least not in a type-safe manner. It would be like a *void** to unknown data. You could try RTTI, but then you can just as well catch the type you would be testing for.

Any useful action on the thrown object involves making some kind of assumption about its type, such as a common base class (e.g. `std::exception` or `myapp::object`), which allows to actually catch that type, making the generic `catch(...)` not necessary.

Usually the least one wants to do when catching an exception is to print a message. That's why it is a good idea to derive exceptions from *std::exception*, which provides that message through the *what()* function. This eliminates the need for *catch(...)*.